# Ubuntu Cronjob can't execute conda environment

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, datascience-anaconda

Whenever I login to my ec2 Ubuntu instance my terminal is like this

```bsh
(base) ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx
```

When I run my Python script which is converted from a Jupyter notebook with the default conda environment the script runs perfect. The problem starts when I try to make a cronjob.

When the instance starts(I will try to explain as best I can), the ipython that runs the script can't find the packages. Because it's the default conda environment. I thought all I have to do is somehow activate the source bash, but everything failed. What I've tried so far

- I've tried to exec bash
- I've tried to add to SHELL the bash
- I've tried to source bash
- I've tried to run ipython directly from conda environment

At this point I don't know what I am missing.
All I want, is when the instance start to "activate" the conda environment and with ipython run the script.

Comment: You need to **show** us what you have tried that worked. What you tried that did not work; And what happened. Hinting at what you did somehow fills my head with ideas— only I don't exactly know what they are. I don't know which of the many ideas are the relevant ones.

Comment: I'll back that up completely. You haven't even shown us your crontab entry. Or how you added it.

Comment: I see that you've added the ways tried by yourself. With your case, sourcing bash should work well. But it failed anyhow like you said above. So I wonder if you choose the right user with cronjob configuring? Of course, I think you'd better fulfill the crontab entry as @roaima said.

Comment: You are right seen from an other perspective my question doesn't make sense, I will update with exactly what I did, and how I enter the crojob as root user and as an ubuntu user(that's how it's called in ec2)

Comment: did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a guess that the virtualenv is being activated in `.profile`, which doesn't affect cron.

I'd suggest activating the venv in the crontab line:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
[crontab stuff]  . /path/to/the/virtualenv/bin/activate && your.py
```

Setting SHELL=/bin/bash is not really mandatory, but will get you closer to the "usual" environment.
If necessary, also set the PATH, cd into the right directory, etc.

A decent way to test is to `ssh you@yourserver 'the command above'`
If you're having trouble getting the error, try appending `&>/tmp/debug.log` to the crontab command.

If you're not sure what the virtualenv path is, try: `type activate` (`echo $PATH`, `print(sys.path)`, etc.)

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv#answer-7031758